# Кеширование TomCat 8 Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: java-ee, сессия

Установил `TomCat 8` на `Ubuntu 16.04`. Завёл `mysql` сервер, залил базу. Задеплоил проект. Открывается - работает. Но фигня в том что при очистке кеша (в хроме) перестаёт работать сайт. Если просто обновить `F5` то всё нормально. Может чиститься сессия?

Comment: Если очищаете `cookie` , то сессия удаляется, и при заходе на сайт создается новая. Это нормальное поведение, как будто первый раз зашли на сайт. А то, что перестает работать сайт - добавьте подробностей.

Comment: @MrFylypenko Почему тогда на локалке сессия не чистится? всё тоже самое от и до. Пропадают данные которые записаны в сессии, которые используются для получения данных из бд.

Comment: К сожалению в вопросе нет данных, чтоб можно было воспроизвести пример и посмотреть, что не так. Поэтому нельзя сказать что у Вас не работает в указанном случае.

Comment: @MrFylypenko  не могу показать код. Конфидециальность на работе.